# How to set margin of ImageView using code, not xml

Tags: android, margin, imageview

I want to add an unknown number of `ImageView` views to my layout with margin. In XML, I can use `layout_margin` like this:

`<ImageView android:layout_margin="5dip" android:src="@drawable/image" />`

There is `ImageView.setPadding()`, but no `ImageView.setMargin()`. I think it's along the lines of `ImageView.setLayoutParams(LayoutParams)`, but not sure what to feed into that.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 403, accepted):

`android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` has a method `setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)`. Direct subclasses are: `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`, `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` and `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Using e.g. `LinearLayout`:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

[MarginLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html)

This sets the margins in pixels. To scale it use

```
context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density
```

[DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density)

Comment: Note that this sets margin size in PIXELS, is not the same as the dpi unit in the xml of this question.

Comment: How can we use a dpi value instead of pixel?

Comment: You can scale the px value using context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density

Comment: Note, that there can be problems with `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` and maybe with other: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401952/framelayout-margin-not-working

Comment: in case we wanted to set only the bottom margin of the image view which is `android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"` in waht way I could accomplish this?

Comment: What if the Parent is a TabHost?

Comment: Didn't work with a radiobutton, any idea about this?

Answer (score 53):

```
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageID);
    MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(image.getLayoutParams());
    marginParams.setMargins(left_margin, top_margin, right_margin, bottom_margin);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
    image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: What's the deal w/ the last 2 lines?  clone the margin params into another params variable?  I can confirm it's required :)

Comment: in case we wanted to set only the bottom margin of the image view which is `android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"` in waht way I could accomplish this?

Comment: layoutparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

Comment: Creating another layout params is required. Thanks :)

Answer (score 51):

All the above examples will actually **REPLACE** any params already present for the View, which may not be desired. The below code will just extend the existing params, without replacing them:

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
MarginLayoutParams marginParams = (MarginLayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams();
marginParams.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Comment: This is the first solution in this list that worked for me. The others screwed up the other params that I had set in the XML, including RelativeLayout params for positioning.

Answer (score 22):

Kevin's code creates redundant `MarginLayoutParams` object. Simpler version:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_image);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(image.getLayoutParams());
lp.setMargins(50, 100, 0, 0);
image.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Weirdly enough I then get "Cannot resolve method setmargins()" which is why I googled for this question and landed here.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to change imageview margin but leave all other margins intact.

1. Get MarginLayoutParameters of your image view in this case: `myImageView`

   ```
    MarginLayoutParams marginParams = (MarginLayoutParams) myImageView.getLayoutParams();
   ```
2. Now just change the margin you want to change but leave the others as they are:

   ```
    marginParams.setMargins(marginParams.leftMargin, 
                            marginParams.topMargin, 
                            150, //notice only changing right margin
                            marginParams.bottomMargin);
   ```

Answer (score 11):

Answer from 2020 year :

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0"
}
```

and cal it simply in your code

```
view.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
   setMargins(5)
}
```

Comment: Works in 2023. As a parameter you should pass pixels, not dp.

Answer (score 9):

I use simply this and works great:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_id);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

*setMargins()*'s unit is pixel not dp. If you want to set margin in dp, just inside your *values/dimens.xml* file create your dimensions like:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="right">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="left">16dp</dimen>    
</resources>
```

and access like:

```
getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.right);
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use kotlin, this can be simplified by creating an extension function

```
fun View.setMarginExtensionFunction(left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
  val params = layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
  params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)
  layoutParams = params
}
```

Now all you need is a view, and this extension function can be used anywhere.

```
val imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
imageView.setMarginExtensionFunction(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: this works for `left` and `right` margins, but if you have relative margins (`start` and `end`) it doesn't work. I wrote a gist with a 'improved' version of your code: https://gist.github.com/Grohden/f40c53bf86c5395638f7a44bf90e732d (the `setMarginsRelative` function) - could you include that in your answer?

Answer (score 8):

You can use this method, in case you want to specify margins in dp:

```
private void addMarginsInDp(View view, int leftInDp, int topInDp, int rightInDp, int bottomInDp) {
    DisplayMetrics dm = view.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(convertDpToPx(leftInDp, dm), convertDpToPx(topInDp, dm), convertDpToPx(rightInDp, dm), convertDpToPx(bottomInDp, dm));
    view.setLayoutParams(lp);
}

private int convertDpToPx(int dp, DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
    float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, displayMetrics);
    return Math.round(pixels);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> create layout dynamically and set its parameter as setmargin() will not work directly on an imageView

```
ImageView im;
im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_image_in_XML_by_id);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(im.getLayoutParams());
                        layout.setMargins(counter*27, 0, 0, 0);//left,right,top,bottom
                        im.setLayoutParams(layout);
                        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourimage)
```

Answer (score 4):

For me this worked:

```
int imgCarMarginRightPx = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, definedValueInDp, res.getDisplayMetrics());

MarginLayoutParams lp = (MarginLayoutParams) imgCar.getLayoutParams();
lp.setMargins(0,0,imgCarMarginRightPx,0);
imgCar.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 2):

> sample code is here ,its very easy

```
LayoutParams params1 = (LayoutParams)twoLetter.getLayoutParams();//twoletter-imageview
                params1.height = 70;
                params1.setMargins(0, 210, 0, 0);//top margin -210 here
                twoLetter.setLayoutParams(params1);//setting layout params
                twoLetter.setImageResource(R.drawable.oo);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin you can write it in more pleasant way

```
myView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            ).apply {
                setMargins(12, 12, 12, 12)
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to add 8px Margin on left, top, right, bottom.

```java
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);

marginLayoutParams.setMargins(8, 8, 8, 8);

imageView.setLayoutParams(marginLayoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a method similar to this might save you some headaches in some situations.
If you have two passes of programmatical tinkering with margins it is safer to check if there are already some layoutParams set. If there are some margins already one should increase them and not replace them:

```
public void addMargins(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
    if (params == null)
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int oldLeft = params.leftMargin;
    int oldTop = params.topMargin;
    int oldRight = params.rightMargin;
    int oldBottom = params.bottomMargin;
    params.setMargins(oldLeft + left, oldTop + top, oldRight + right, oldBottom + bottom);
    v.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create **Linear LayoutParams** & use **resources.getDimensionPixelSize** for dp value.

```
    val mContext = parent.context
    val mImageView = AppCompatImageView(mContext)
    mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.payment_method_selector)

    val height = mContext.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.payment_logo_height)
    val width = mContext.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.payment_logo_width)
    val padding = mContext.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.spacing_small_tiny)
    val margin = mContext.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.spacing_small)

    mImageView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height).apply {
        setMargins(margin, margin, 0, 0)
    }
    mImageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding)
```