# how to set image's margin top using coding not xml in android

Tags: android

i am using  android:layout_marginTop="100dip" in my imageview,i want to set margin top to each image depending its height using coding not using xml,how can i set image's margintop?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416087/how-to-set-margin-of-imageview-using-code-not-xml/3416242#3416242

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
public void setMargins (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

Comment: @Thanks Jackn,i want to display all images in center position in screen,in case image size is 50X50,this image display center in screen,other wise other images are display in it's original view.How it is possible in android