# FrameLayout margin not working

Tags: android, android-layout

My layout structure is like this

```
LinearLayout
    FrameLayout
       ImageView
       ImageView
    FrameLayout
    TextView
LinearLayout
```

I have set margin's for the two ImageView which are inside FrameLayout. But FrameLayout margins are discarded and it always set's the Image to top left corner. If i change from FrameLayout to LinearLayout the margin's work properly. How to handle this ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/inner1"
    >
        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

            <ImageView
             android:layout_width="24px" 
             android:layout_height="24px" 
             android:id="@+id/favicon"
             android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
             android:layout_marginTop="50px"
             android:layout_marginBottom="40px"
             android:layout_marginRight="70px"      

            />      
            <ImageView
             android:layout_width="52px" 
             android:layout_height="52px" 
             android:id="@+id/applefavicon" 
             android:layout_marginLeft="100px"
             android:layout_marginTop="100px"
             android:layout_marginBottom="100px"
             android:layout_marginRight="100px"              
            />

        </FrameLayout>  
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/title"                 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10px"        
            android:layout_marginTop="20px"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"  
            android:textSize = "15px"
            android:singleLine = "true"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 225, accepted):

I had the same issue myself and noticed that setting the `layout_` margins does not work until you also set your ImageView's layout gravity i.e. `android:layout_gravity="top"` in the XML resource file, or from code: `FrameLayout.LayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;`.

Comment: It works, but it makes me feel dirty. I thought I had escaped the days of CSS hacks...

Comment: FrameLayout.LayoutParams.gravity does not have a gravity option in 2.3

Comment: It seems to be fixed on 4.1 (probably before). Useful to know though

Comment: fixed an issue I was having on the old kindle fire. Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone explain why this works?  This makes absolutely no sense why this fixes it.

Comment: To make it more clear why. The FrameLayout.onLayout() call contains this (in api v2.3.4 at least):
`// for each child:
 final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
 final int gravity = lp.gravity;
        if (gravity != -1) {
            // handle all margin related stuff
`
So if gravity is -1, there will be no margin calculation. Gravity in FrameLayout.LayoutParams is defined by:
`gravity = a.getInt(com.android.internal.R.styleable.FrameLayout_Layout_layout_gravity, -1);
`
So if gravity is not set, there will be no margin calculation.

Comment: May be helpfull: this is fix on 4.0.4

Comment: In 4.2 works fine w/o any changes, but on 2.3 works only with the described fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

To make it more clear why. The FrameLayout.onLayout() call contains this (in api v2.3.4 at least):

```
    // for each child
    final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    final int gravity = lp.gravity;
    if (gravity != -1) {
        // handle all margin related stuff
```

So if gravity is -1, there will be no margin calculation. And the thing is, gravity in FrameLayout.LayoutParams is defined by:

```
    gravity = a.getInt(com.android.internal.R.styleable.FrameLayout_Layout_layout_gravity, -1);
```

So if gravity is not set, there will be no margin calculation.

Answer (score 7):

add your xml this attribute and re run

android:layout_gravity="top"

everything is Ok!

and you dont set new layout params like this;

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams llp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(WallpapersActivity.ScreenWidth/2, layH);
```

use like this:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams llp = (LayoutParams) myFrameLay.getLayoutParams();
llp.height = 100;
llp.width = 100;
myFrameLay.setLayoutParams(llp);
```

Comment: So if you don't have LayoutParams, it will crash with the second method.

Comment: you can check it with if == null control.

Comment: This solve my problem with margin_top on Android 10.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the FrameLayout docs ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html))

> The size of the frame layout is the size of its largest child (plus padding), visible or not (if the FrameLayout's parent permits).

This seems to describe the fact that it'll strip margins out. Like boulder mentioned, you could try switching to padding as it can be used to produce a similar effect if done properly.

Out of curiosity, you mentioned that it does work fine when using a `LinearLayout` container, why the choice of FrameLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried android:layout_gravity ? Try using android:padding in you ImageViews instead of android:layout_margin. AFAIK margins doesn't work properly on Frame layout. I even had to write custom layout for that purpose once. BTW, how do you want allign you ImageViews?

Comment: there is no weight in a framelayout

Answer (score 0):

try setCropToPadding(true) to ImageView ,this should be helped!

Answer (score 0):

you have to set your ImageView's layout gravity top i.e. android:layout_gravity="top" in the XML resource file, or from code: FrameLayout.LayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP