# create a linear layout of overlapping imageviews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, imageview, android-linearlayout

I need to create a stack of overlapping `ImageViews` in Android like Spider Solitaire in Windows. Also, I need to be able to dynamically add more `ImageViews`. Please suggest methods to do so. Can I use a `LinearLayout` (Its not necessary. Whatever works is fine)? If so, how do I accomplish the overlap?

Note: All the `ImageViews` will have the same amount of overlap, so no need to worry about the unopened cards in the give screenshot.

[image: solitaire]

Thank You

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this using `Linearlayout`

Comment: @SMR Whatever works is fine. `LinearLayout` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

User [LayerList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)

```
A LayerDrawable is a drawable object that manages an array of other drawables. 
Each drawable in the list is drawn in the order of the list—the last drawable in the list is drawn on top.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_red"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item android:top="10dp" >
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_green"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item android:top="20dp" >
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Note :** the below images uses item attributes as android:left="10dp", android:left="20dp".

[image]

Comment: How do I add new Layers in it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FrameLayout`. Following layout is an example with 3 `ImageViews`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#f00" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#0f0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="#00f" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I need to add more `ImageView`s dynamically. How do I do that? I dont see a function to edit the `layout_margin...` attribute of the view.

Comment: Refer this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101532/android-set-margins-in-a-framelayout-programmatically-not-working

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this using `Linearlayout` only.

But you can use [LayerList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)

> A `LayerDrawable` is a drawable object that manages an array of other
>   drawables. Each drawable in the list is drawn in the order of the
>   list—the last drawable in the list is drawn on top.

with help of LayerList you can achieve the following:

[image: preview]

#### Syntax

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@[package:]drawable/drawable_resource"
        android:id="@[+][package:]id/resource_name"
        android:top="dimension"
        android:right="dimension"
        android:bottom="dimension"
        android:left="dimension" />
</layer-list>
```

Comment: How do I add more layers in it dynamically?