# Align a text programatically with bottom,right params from FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I'm trying align a text with the params of Framelayout using bottom and right but is not working. Here's the code:

```
FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame1);

TextView text = (TextView)frame.findViewById(R.id.text);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
params.setMargins(0,0,100,100);     
text.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The default align of FrameLayout is top and left margins, but on my application i have to use bottom and right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this will work , could you try to put this

```
 params.gravity = (Gravity.BOTTOM |Gravity.RIGHT);
```

please leave a comment if it does or dosent' work for you

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to set a `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` gravity, like below:

```
 params.gravity = (Gravity.BOTTOM |Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Hope it help.

Comment: chack also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101532/android-set-margins-in-a-framelayout-programmatically-not-working