# Android FrameLayout different behavior API 10 and 11

Tags: android, api, android-framelayout, multiple-versions

I was designed a view with a FrameLayout as the parent of an ImageView and TextView and when testing on devices with API <10 I've realized that the FrameLayout height doesn't obey to the fill_parent rule (every component is overlayed)

Nevertheless, on Android 4.x it seems to work fine.

Any ideias?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably show the layout you're using. Nevertheless, "[`FrameLayout` is designed to block out an area on the screen to display **a single item**.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)" You should use a different layout type instead, depending on your needs.

Comment: I've something like:
<FrameLayout>
  <LinearLayout>
  <TextView>
</FrameLayout>

Hmmm... nevertheless, it works properly on Android 4.x. Is there any  workaround to allow multiple views?

Comment: Yeah, use a different type of layout! ;) If you want them stacked Z-wise, use `RelativeLayout`; X- or Z-wise, use `LinearLayout`. For grids, perhaps `TableLayout` or `GridLayout`. It all depends what you want the end result to look like.

Comment: I need to use a FrameLayout for drag and drop content - or is there another type of layout I could use?

Comment: I've not used drag and drop functionality, but you should be able to use other types of layouts also. I mean, [here's one for `GridLayout`](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html#tutorial_draganddrop3), for example. (Google has others, as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, the margins were ignored under FrameLayout in v2.x vs 4.x
Found answer here:
[FrameLayout margin not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401952/framelayout-margin-not-working)

In short- use: android:layout_gravity="top"