# Only last added button is shown

Tags: java, android, button, android-framelayout, layoutparams

I am trying to add 9 buttons programmatically to a `FrameLayout` but only the last one is shown.

The code below is for the first button and I am doing like that for all the other buttons, but with different coordinates.

I want to add each button with these exact coordinates.

Sorry for bad English ;)

```
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button button1 = new Button(this);
    button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.empty);
    rel_btn.width = screenWidth/4;
    rel_btn.height = screenWidth/4; 
    rel_btn.leftMargin = screenWidth/8;
    rel_btn.topMargin = screenHeight-1100;              
    button1.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);
    rl.addView(button1);
```

Comment: Can you give more details on what your app does and why you need to have exact pixel-based layout of buttons?

Comment: I am beginner and for learning I am trying to make a tic tac toe .I want it to be good on different devices with different resolutions .

Comment: I edited my answer with advice to use an xml based layout using `dp`'s instead of pixels if you want it to work well on different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

A FrameLayout "is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item". The last child view is displayed on top of all the earlier views. If you want them all to display in a vertical list, a LinearLayout would be better suited to what you are trying to do.

Edit: If you want it to work reliably on different screen sizes and resolutions you shouldn't use pixels, you should define your layout in xml using `dp`s instead of pixels. You could make your root layout a RelativeLayout and define relationships for each of the buttons such as `android:toRightOf="<id of button>"`

Comment: I doubt that `stacking` is the issue here. OP said: `The code I show you is for the first button and I am doing like that for other button of course with different coordinates`.

Comment: Stacking sounds exactly like the issue described by the OP "but only the last one is shown"

Comment: Yes it does. Except that OP _also_ says that s/he is using different coordinates for every `Button`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer that might explain your problem: [FrameLayout margin not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401952/framelayout-margin-not-working)

FrameLayout may be ignoring the margins because you didn't specify a gravity. Try adding a gravity: `rel_btn.gravity = Gravity.TOP;`