# Top margin of SwipeRefreshLayout in Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-layout

I have `SwipeRefreshLayout` inside `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/fr_projects_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        [...]
   </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And i want to add top margin for it:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams ps = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mRefreshLayout.getLayoutParams(); 
ps.topMargin = 40;
mRefreshLayout.setLayoutParams(ps);
mRefreshLayout.requestLayout();
```

It works fine on Android 4.0+. But on Android 2.3 instead of top margin i see bot margin. And really can't understand what happens. Any suggestions?

If i change `FrameLayout` to `RelativeLayout` it works fine everywhere...

Comment: possible duplicate of [FrameLayout margin not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401952/framelayout-margin-not-working)

Comment: my question was "why it works on 4.0 and doesn't work on 2.3"

Comment: It's a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28057) that was fixed in Honeycomb.

Comment: @corsair992 in this issue layout_marginTop is fully ignored, but in my case i see it, but in bottom =/

Comment: Maybe your layout just ends naturally at the margin. Without knowing the whole of your layout, we can't figure out for sure exactly what's going on. Some screenshots would also help. In any case, it's clear that `FrameLayout` margins were buggy pre-Honeycomb, so what's the purpose of figuring out exactly what's going on? Just use another layout, or the gravity workaround.

Comment: @corsair992 yeh, now i'm using RelativeLayout