# android tablerow convert xml to code

Tags: android, textview

How do you convert the xml below to java code in an activity?...

```
    <TableRow android:background="#00ff00" android:layout_margin="2dip">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/firstview"  android:layout_margin="2dip"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/someview"  android:layout_margin="2dip"/>

    </TableRow>
```

this is an example taken from
http://www.droidnova.com/display-borders-in-tablelayout,112.html

Comment: Just to confirm, this TableRow will be a child of a TableLayout and you just want to be able to add the views programmatically, correct?

Comment: correct, my tablelayout will be declared in XML, but tablerows will need to be created dynamically. =)    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:stretchColumns="*" android:background="#FFFFFF">

Comment: in java code i have TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);...................table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Comment: I know I need something like LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParam, but I just can't get it right...when I do row.addView(someView, lp) the someView does not display...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)

> The children of a TableLayout cannot
>   specify the layout_width attribute.
>   Width is always MATCH_PARENT. However,
>   the layout_height attribute can be
>   defined by a child; default value is
>   WRAP_CONTENT. If the child is a
>   TableRow, then the height is always
>   WRAP_CONTENT.

Try updating your LayoutParams to use MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT for the width and height respectively.

Comment: I can't compile with MATCH_PARENT...I got the code from http://huuah.com/using-tablelayout-on-android/ this part of it seems to work correctly

Comment: Try FILL_PARENT. MATCH_PARENT was added in API 8 to replace FILL_PARENT

Comment: I think its the way I am declaring layout_margin in TableRow and TextView. So I think if I can some how convert that XML on top to java code it will work...

Comment: That's okay :) Just use FILL_PARENT instead of MATCH_PARENT. It should work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Give an `id` to `TableRow` in xml files, for example, `myRow`

Java code:

```
TableRow tr = (TableRow)this.findViewById(R.id.myRow);

TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lp.setMargins(4, 4, 4, 4);

TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tr.addView(tv1, lp);

TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
tr.addView(tv2, lp);
```

in that way, you could set the margin.

en, setMargins using px, you should changed 2dip into px yourself.

I come here for asking the same question, and i get answer from this title:
[How to set margin of ImageView using code, not xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416087/how-to-set-margin-of-imageview-using-code-not-xml)