# Setting margins for an imageview dynamically

Tags: android, android-imageview, margins

may I know how to set margin in imageview dynamically?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416087/how-to-set-margin-of-imageview-using-code-not-xml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)

Note this part of the method description though:

> These supply parameters to the parent of this view specifying how it
>   should be arranged

Which means that if you have an ImageView inside of a LinearLayout, you need to supply the method with LinearLayout.LayoutParams, like this:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
params.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
image.setLayoutParams(params);
```

And then you just call setMargins or set the specific leftMargin, bottomMargin etc. properties of the LayoutParams.

Comment: How to set margins for relative layout?