# position of drawable inside edittext

Tags: java, android, position, android-edittext, drawable

I put a drawable into a edittext by this code:

```
    final Drawable x = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.del2);
    x.setBounds(0, 0, x.getIntrinsicWidth(), x.getIntrinsicHeight());
    atxt.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, x, null);
```

With this code my drawable shows in right side of edittext, I want to set margin for it. For example if i set rightMargin:20dp my drawable goes a little to left side. How i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
x.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416087/how-to-set-margin-of-imageview-using-code-not-xml)