# Relocate View in API 1 friendly way

Tags: android

The below code needs API 11 - how would I write this to support API level 1? I just want to relocate a view.

```
ImageView imageviewLogo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewLogo);
imageviewLogo.setY(imageviewLogo.getHeight());
```

Comment: Not that it will help for this particular method, but do you really need to support API level 1? I would start at 10 for anything new, or even 15 if it was a few months before I expected to release. A more recent API level will save you a lot of time and frustration, assuming you don't absolutely _need_ API 1 (to support an HTC Dream that hasn't been updated?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to update the margins and use that to relocate the view. Here is a good example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3416242/969325):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

and perhaps invalidate layout after the margins are updated.