# How can I set Margin in Code-behind for MonoDroid?

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin.android, xamarin

this question is simple, but i'm not finding nothing about it. How can i set margin into a widget in code-behind.

I found this document into [Xamarin's site](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.Views.ViewGroup%2bMarginLayoutParams.SetMargins%28System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32%29), but i can't use this into a ImageView

I also tried the method Layout() in my ImageView, but it didn't work.

```
        ImageView imgView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
        imgView.Layout(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416087/how-to-set-margin-of-imageview-using-code-not-xml

Comment: I already had seem it, and this method doesn't exist in xamarin. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using FrameLayout's LayoutParams?

Here is an example:

Your image:

```
ImageView imgView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
```

Your image's parameters:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams imgViewParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, 0.0f);
imgViewParams.SetMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

Setting your image's parameters:

```
imgView.LayoutParameters = imgViewParams;
```

EDIT: Changed **LinearLayout**.LayoutParameters to **FrameLayout**.LayoutParameters!

Comment: i was trying to create a LinearLayout.LayoutParams and set into the ImageView, but the problem was that i had a Frame Layout instead of a Linear Layout, I just changed to FrameLayout.LayoutParams and it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a LinearLayout to your layout?

You could wrap your ImageView inside it and add margins!

Like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >
    <ImageView
        your imageview stuff />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps but you could try changing margin values like this and see how well this works:

```
imgView.margin = new thickness(leftvalue,topvalue,rightvalue,botvalue);
```