# Android Framelayout Displays single ImageButton

Tags: android, android-framelayout

Here is my Camera Fragment Framelayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/sc_background">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sc_camera_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sc_btn_flip_camera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/sc_ic_camera_switch"
            style="?attr/scButtonSwitchCameraStyle"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sc_btn_take_picture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/sc_ic_camera"
            style="?attr/scButtonTakePictureStyle"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sc_btn_record_video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/sc_ic_video"
            style="?attr/scButtonRecordVideoStyle"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sc_btn_stop_recording_video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/sc_ic_stop"
            style="?attr/scButtonStopRecordingStyle"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

But it displays only sc_btn_take_picture when I run the program on my phone.

```
    private static final String TAG = SimpleCameraFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final int MENU_ITEM_QUALITY = 18438;


    interface Contract {

        void onPictureTaken(File photo);

        void onVideoRecorded(File video);

        void startSwitchingCamera(boolean currentlyFront);

        void changeCameraContainerSize(int width, int height);
    }

    public static SimpleCameraFragment newInstance(
            boolean startWithFrontFacingCamera,
            boolean camIsSwitchable,
            File directory,
            String location,
            Size pictureSize) {

        SimpleCameraFragment fragment = new SimpleCameraFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle(5);
        args.putBoolean(KEY_USE_FFC, startWithFrontFacingCamera);
        args.putBoolean(KEY_CAM_SWITCHABLE, camIsSwitchable);
        args.putString(KEY_FILE_DIR, directory == null ? null : directory.getPath());
        args.putString(KEY_FILE_NAME, location != null ? location : UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        args.putInt(KEY_PICTURE_SIZE, pictureSize.ordinal());

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public enum Size {
        AVATAR(640 * 480),
        NORMAL(1280 * 960);

        private final int product;

        Size(int product) {
            this.product = product;
        }

        static Size tryOrdinal(int ordinal) {
            for (Size size : values()) {
                if (size.ordinal() == ordinal) {
                    return size;
                }
            }
            return NORMAL;
        }
    }

    public static final String KEY_USE_FFC = "com.askcs.teamup.ui.fragment.CameraFragment.USE_FFC";
    public static final String KEY_CAM_SWITCHABLE = "com.askcs.teamup.ui.fragment.CameraFragment.CAM_IS_SWITCHABLE";
    public static final String KEY_FILE_DIR = "com.askcs.teamup.ui.fragment.CameraFragment.FILE_DIR";
    public static final String KEY_FILE_NAME = "com.askcs.teamup.ui.fragment.CameraFragment.EXTRA_FILENAME";
    public static final String KEY_PICTURE_SIZE = "com.askcs.teamup.ui.fragment.CameraFragment.PICTURE_SIZE";

    private Contract contractor;
    private String flashMode = null;

    private boolean useFrontFacingCamera;
    private boolean canSwitchCamera;
    private boolean autoFocusAvailable;
    private File finalFile;
    private File dir;
    private String fileName;

    private int jpegQuality = 85;
    private Size imageSize = Size.NORMAL;

    private ImageButton btnTakePicture;
    private ImageButton btnSwitchCamera;
    private ImageButton btnRecordVideo;
    private ImageButton btnStopRecordingVideo;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        String dirString = getArguments().getString(KEY_FILE_DIR);
        fileName = getArguments().getString(KEY_FILE_NAME);
        imageSize = Size.tryOrdinal(getArguments().getInt(KEY_PICTURE_SIZE, 0));
        useFrontFacingCamera = getArguments().getBoolean(KEY_USE_FFC);
        canSwitchCamera = getArguments().getBoolean(KEY_CAM_SWITCHABLE);

        dir = TextUtils.isEmpty(dirString) ? getActivity().getCacheDir() : new File(dirString);

        SimpleCameraHost.Builder builder =
                new SimpleCameraHost.Builder(new CameraHost(getActivity()));

        builder.useFullBleedPreview(false);

        setCameraHost(builder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        FrameLayout root = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.sc_camera_fragment, null);

        ((FrameLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.sc_camera_container)).addView(view);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (autoFocusAvailable) {
                    autoFocus();
                }
            }
        });

        btnTakePicture = (ImageButton) root.findViewById(R.id.sc_btn_take_picture);
        btnTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onTakePictureClick();
            }
        });

        btnSwitchCamera = (ImageButton) root.findViewById(R.id.sc_btn_flip_camera);
        btnSwitchCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onSwitchCameraClick();
            }
        });

        btnRecordVideo = (ImageButton) root.findViewById(R.id.sc_btn_record_video);
        btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onRecordVideoClick();
            }
        });

        btnStopRecordingVideo = (ImageButton) root.findViewById(R.id.sc_btn_stop_recording_video);
        btnStopRecordingVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onStopRecordVideoClick();
            }
        });

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        resetButtons();
    }

    void onTakePictureClick() {

        btnTakePicture.setEnabled(false);
        btnSwitchCamera.setEnabled(false);
        btnRecordVideo.setEnabled(false);

        takePicture();
    }

    void onSwitchCameraClick() {

        // Disable functions to prevent issues during fragment replacement
        btnTakePicture.setEnabled(false);
        btnSwitchCamera.setEnabled(false);
        btnRecordVideo.setEnabled(false);
        btnStopRecordingVideo.setEnabled(false);

        // Tell the parent activity to replace this fragment by the one with the 'different' camera view
        // If current is front, change to back. If current is back, change to front.
        ((SimpleCameraActivity) getActivity()).startSwitchingCamera( useFrontFacingCamera );

    }

    void onRecordVideoClick() {

        btnTakePicture.setEnabled(false);
        btnTakePicture.setVisibility(GONE);

        btnSwitchCamera.setEnabled(false);
        btnSwitchCamera.setVisibility(GONE);

        btnRecordVideo.setEnabled(false);
        btnRecordVideo.setVisibility(GONE);

        btnStopRecordingVideo.setEnabled(true);
        btnStopRecordingVideo.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

        try {
            record();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Something went wrong while calling record()", e);
        }
    }

    void onStopRecordVideoClick() {

        btnStopRecordingVideo.setEnabled(false);

        try {
            stopRecording();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Something went wrong while calling stopRecording()", e);
        }
    }

    void resetButtons() {

        if (btnTakePicture != null) {
            btnTakePicture.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            btnTakePicture.setEnabled(true);
        }

        if (btnRecordVideo != null) {
            btnRecordVideo.setVisibility(GONE);
            btnRecordVideo.setEnabled(false);
        }

        // Check if we have to show the switch camera button
        if (btnSwitchCamera != null) {

            if(canSwitchCamera) {
                btnSwitchCamera.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                btnSwitchCamera.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                btnSwitchCamera.setVisibility(GONE);
                btnSwitchCamera.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }

        if (btnStopRecordingVideo != null) {
            btnStopRecordingVideo.setVisibility(GONE);
            btnStopRecordingVideo.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        this.contractor = (Contract) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        this.contractor = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void takePicture() {
        if (!btnTakePicture.isEnabled()) {

            btnTakePicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnTakePicture.setEnabled(false);

            super.takePicture(new PictureTransaction(getCameraHost()).flashMode(flashMode).mirrorFFC(true));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stopRecording() throws IOException {
        super.stopRecording();

        contractor.onVideoRecorded(finalFile);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        MenuItem qualitySlider = menu.add(0, MENU_ITEM_QUALITY, 0, R.string.sc_menu_label_quality);
        MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(qualitySlider, MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case MENU_ITEM_QUALITY:

                new DialogFragment() {

                    private int newJpegQuality;

                    @Override
                    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                        LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.sc_dialog_quality, null);

                        SeekBar qualityBar = (SeekBar) rootView.getChildAt(0);
                        qualityBar.setMax(50);
                        qualityBar.setProgress(jpegQuality - 50);
                        qualityBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                                if (fromUser) {
                                    newJpegQuality = 50 + progress;
                                    getDialog().setTitle(getString(R.string.sc_image_quality, new Object[]{newJpegQuality}));
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                                // ignored
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                                // ignored
                            }
                        });

                        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                                .setTitle("Image quality: " + jpegQuality + "%")
                                .setView(rootView)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        jpegQuality = newJpegQuality;
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                })
                                .create();
                    }
                }.show(getFragmentManager(), "quality-slider");

                return true;
        }

        return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }

    class CameraHost extends SimpleCameraHost {

        public CameraHost(Context _ctxt) {
            super(_ctxt);
        }

        @Override
        public Camera.Parameters adjustPictureParameters(PictureTransaction xact, Camera.Parameters parameters) {

            parameters.setJpegQuality(jpegQuality);

            for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
                Log.v(TAG, "w=" + size.width + ", h=" + size.height);
            }

            return parameters;
        }

        @Override
        public Camera.Size getPictureSize(PictureTransaction xact, Camera.Parameters parameters) {

            List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
            ArrayList<Integer> calculated = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                calculated.add(size.height * size.width);
            }

            int closestIndexUntilNow = 0;
            int lastDelta = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int i = 0; i < calculated.size(); i++) {

                int delta = Math.abs(imageSize.product - calculated.get(i));

                if (delta < lastDelta) {
                    closestIndexUntilNow = i;
                }

                lastDelta = delta;
            }

            Camera.Size size = sizes.get(closestIndexUntilNow);

            Log.v(TAG, "Chosen size: w=" + size.width + ", h=" + size.height);

            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public float maxPictureCleanupHeapUsage() {
            return super.maxPictureCleanupHeapUsage();
        }

        @Override
        protected File getPhotoPath() {

            if (finalFile == null) {
                finalFile = super.getPhotoPath();
            }

            return finalFile;
        }

        @Override
        public RecordingHint getRecordingHint() {
            return RecordingHint.STILL_ONLY;
        }

        @Override
        protected File getVideoPath() {

            if (finalFile == null) {
                finalFile = super.getVideoPath();
            }

            return finalFile;
        }

        @Override
        protected File getPhotoDirectory() {
            return dir;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getPhotoFilename() {

            if (!fileName.endsWith(".jpg")) {
                fileName += ".jpg";
            }

            Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(fileName));

            return fileName;
        }

        @Override
        protected File getVideoDirectory() {
            return dir;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getVideoFilename() {

            if (!fileName.endsWith(".mp4")) {
                fileName += ".mp4";
            }

            Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(fileName));

            return fileName;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean useFrontFacingCamera() {
            return useFrontFacingCamera;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean useSingleShotMode() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void saveImage(PictureTransaction xact, byte[] image) {

            File photo = getPhotoPath();

            if (photo.exists()) {
                photo.delete();
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                bos.write(image);
                bos.flush();
                fos.getFD().sync();
                bos.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                handleException(e);
            }

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    btnTakePicture.setEnabled(false);
                    btnRecordVideo.setEnabled(false);
                    btnStopRecordingVideo.setEnabled(false);

                    btnTakePicture.setVisibility(GONE);
                    btnRecordVideo.setVisibility(GONE);
                    btnStopRecordingVideo.setVisibility(GONE);

                    resetButtons();

                    contractor.onPictureTaken(new File(dir, fileName));
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void autoFocusAvailable() {
            autoFocusAvailable = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void autoFocusUnavailable() {
            autoFocusAvailable = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCameraFail(com.google.cam2.camera.CameraHost.FailureReason reason) {
            super.onCameraFail(reason);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Sorry, but you cannot use the camera now!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public Camera.Parameters adjustPreviewParameters(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
            flashMode =
                    CameraUtils.findBestFlashModeMatch(parameters,
                            Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_RED_EYE,
                            Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO,
                            Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);

            List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            ArrayList<Integer> calculated = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                calculated.add(size.height * size.width);
            }

            int closestIndexUntilNow = 0;
            int lastDelta = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int i = 0; i < calculated.size(); i++) {

                int delta = Math.abs(imageSize.product - calculated.get(i));

                if (delta < lastDelta) {
                    closestIndexUntilNow = i;
                }

                lastDelta = delta;
            }

            Camera.Size size = sizes.get(closestIndexUntilNow);

            parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);

            return (super.adjustPreviewParameters(parameters));
        }

        @Override
        public Camera.Size getPreviewSize(int displayOrientation, int width, int height, Camera.Parameters parameters) {

            List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            ArrayList<Integer> calculated = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                calculated.add(size.width * size.height);
            }

            int closestIndexUntilNow = 0;
            int lastDelta = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int i = 0; i < calculated.size(); i++) {

                int delta = Math.abs(imageSize.product - calculated.get(i));

                if (delta < lastDelta) {
                    closestIndexUntilNow = i;
                }

                lastDelta = delta;
            }

            Camera.Size size = sizes.get(closestIndexUntilNow);
//            contractor.changeCameraContainerSize(size.width, size.height);

            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean mirrorFFC() {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

So far I tried adding LinearLayout on the Parent FrameLayout. I Have also Added the image buttons directly in the Framelayout. But when I run in onto my device it just shows the sc_btn_take_picture. I am attaching the screenshots too.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you try to add android:orientation="vertical" to your LinearLayout?

Comment: Yes I did try with both the orientation

Comment: can you show what type of design you want ? Because you inflate something in onCreate.

Comment: Yes explain what you want to do something like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34918804/android-take-multiple-image-with-camera/34920241#34920241
check the picture

Comment: I have added the implementation I am trying to do but as of I just need to get the buttons available on the screen. So I can test the camera features

Comment: I have tried both orientations horizontal and vertical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your `resetButtons()` method where things are mostly being set to `setVisibility(GONE);`

The `btnTakePicture` is set as visible, the `btnSwitchCamera` is set to be visible only if `canSwitchCamera` is true, but we can't see where that is set from your code. The other buttons are set as gone in the `resetButtons()` method.

Comment: I have added the complete Fragment Code could you go through it once?

Comment: When you are creating your fragment using `SimpleCameraFragment.newInstance()`, the second parameter determines whether the btnSwitchCamera will be shown or not, if that second parameter is false then you will only see one of the buttons on screen as all the others as set to `GONE` in the `resetButtons()` method

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add    android:orientation="horizontal" to your linear layout where you are setting those camera control image buttons