# Place the same image on screen multiple times whenever button clicked

Tags: java, android, dynamic, imageview

when the user clicks on the button the same image will display again and again on multiple locations. I am using on touch listener to move images. that is working but I can't create multiple images with the same imageview or with for loop please help. This is the image I want to create multiple time 
**This is my xml**

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/main_html"
tools:context="com.incubers.signondoc.ui.HtmlActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/save_edited"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    style="?android:button"
    android:text="@string/hint_save" />


<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:id="@+id/viewpdfHtml"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageSign"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/no_connection" />

</com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView>`
```

**This is my ontouchlistener for moving images and other code**

```
ImageView imageView;
 ViewGroup mainLayout;
 private View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener() {
    return (view, event) -> {
        final int x = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int y = (int) event.getRawY();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                        view.getLayoutParams();
                xDelta = x - lParams.leftMargin;
                yDelta = y - lParams.topMargin;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                float xD = event.getX();
                float yD = event.getY();
                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                float   XDis = displayMetrics.xdpi;
                float  YDis = displayMetrics.ydpi;
                finalX = xD/XDis*100;
                finalY  = yD/YDis*100;

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                        .getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = x - xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = y - yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = 0;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                break;

        }
        mainLayout.invalidate();
        return true;
    };
}
```

**this is the button which should show images on  click**

```
  buttonSign.setOnClickListener(view ->{

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create ImageView dynamically to make this work, this might help you :

[Create ImageViews dynamically inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356473/create-imageviews-dynamically-inside-a-loop)

Comment: I have added that code inside onclick method and got this error   The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: Have you removed the ImageView from your layout? Please update your code in the question so that i can help you.

Comment: one more thing if you can help that how can I remove these images from view?

Comment: how are you setting the images in code ? If you are using image.setImageDrawable(drawable); set it to image.setImageDrawable(null);

Comment: i am getting it from phone storage image.setImageURI

Comment: try setting image.setImageURI(null)

Comment: i have created another button for clear images should i placed image.setImageURI(null) inside it?

Comment: i have defined ImageView image; globally and it is working but just clearing the last image

Comment: final ImageView[] image = new ImageView[1];

Comment: You need to somehow keep track of every ImageView you create, use an array of ImageView and keep adding new ImageView's in it, clear the ImageView based on their position.