# getting leftMargin of imageView after Gravity.CENTER

Tags: android, textview

I have been trying with `TextView` and `drawableLeft` images.
but, `drawableLeft` tend to stick to left everytime(unless `TextView.WRAP_CONTENT`) .

I have `TextViews` arranged in my vertical Layout one below another(everything has a `drawableLeft` too)

I changed one of the  `TextView`+`drawableLeft` to `RelativeLayout`+(`TextView` and `ImageView` .
Applied gravity to center

I was trying to get the left margin of `ImageView` ,so that I can apply it to later `TextView` as padding using 
setPadding(IMAGE_PADDING,0,0,0)

how can I get the left margin from code . 
I tried

```
imageView.getPaddingLeft();
```

its returning 0;

Am I doing it wrong ? is there a way to get it?

Help and Advises needed

Comment: you are using a drawableLeft property of a textView to stick Somewhere else in TextView ?? can you please clearify exactly what you want. or if possible share your xml code or images of what you want.

Comment: @Manish I am using  5 TextViews with drawableLeft in it , what I basically wanted is to get Text and image centered for each TextView.

Comment: check my answer and tell me if it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Set margin like this :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

**Note** : This sets margin size in PIXELS, is not the same as the dpi.

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416087/how-to-set-margin-of-imageview-using-code-not-xml)