# How can I manage the gap between dynamically created imageViews?

Tags: android, css

[image]Everthnig comes correctily but i need to have a vertical gap between this.Please halp me !!

This is my code .

```
 for(int i=0;i<value1;i++) {
            //Add images
            ImageView image = new ImageView(HomePage.this);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulb1);
            image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            image.setPadding(8, 8, 8,8 );
            image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    }
```

Comment: Is it list view or recycler view?

Comment: It is a linear layout.

Comment: I just added my code to the question! Help me please!

Comment: Padding is the spacing between the view's bounds and its content. Margin is the spacing outside the view's bounds which cannot be occupied by any other view. In your case, you are using padding where you should be using margins.

Comment: I think using a list view or recycler view will be more efficient here. Are you sure you want to stick to this way of doing it ?

Comment: Ya actually i can't take it to a list view cause there's lot of things i need to add dynamically

Comment: yeah i got the answer by giving a height value to textviews! Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add a **TextView**(add width=10dp and height=**X**dp, here **X** is your required gap between those images) which does not contain any text after every BulbImage. Those **TextView** will help you to manage gap between images.

You can also add bottom margin to all images.

Answer (score 0):

> You can add a margin to image like this

```
GridView.LayoutParams params = new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85);
params.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
image.setLayoutParams(params);
```

> if you have an ImageView inside of a GridView, you need to supply
>   the method with GridView.LayoutParams like that etc..

Comment: setMargins() does not support for image views

Comment: are you sure ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416087/how-to-set-margin-of-imageview-using-code-not-xml