# Icon margin/padding destroyed

Tags: java, android

> I've created a refresh animation to my icon. But after setting the
>   imageResource to the button the layout is broken.

[image]

> Before creating my animation and setting the imageResource the button
>   looked like this with margin/padding:

[image]

I've set the imageResource with following code:

```js
ImageView reloadButton = (ImageView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_reloaditem).getActionView();

reloadButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_reloadentry);
```

Unable to track reason for this issue. Any help would be really valuable.

Comment: Check drawable dpi image... If you have all drawable images resolution for both

Comment: Look at your xml code. the "plus" button is likely a part of your xml code. Since you added the reloadbutton programatically maybe that´s the issue? i.e set a margin and padding here in your java code.

Comment: The are exactly the same. The plus is just set from xml and the reload button in the programm

Comment: Look at this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416087/how-to-set-margin-of-imageview-using-code-not-xml maybe this will help.

Comment: @Tacolibre I've set the reload icon at the menu item in xml too but the animation on this is removing this icon so you need to set it new like I did. But it looks like that padding/margin is missing. The problem is I don't know the exact margins from the standard layout

Answer (score 0):

check whether icon images are having same size. resolution

Comment: They are the same resolution ;) before creating an animation I've set the same icon as a normal icon to the bar and I looks brilliant with padding/margin like the plus icon

Comment: But when you create an animation you need to set a resource manually in the program and thats the problem. The xml know the margin/padding (just an idea)

Comment: you are using ImageView instead of ImageButton

Comment: create a layout for the menu icons, set padding and margin for the layout instead of button and try.