# How to move to a different x,y location on a screen programatically in oncreate(android)

Tags: android, view, focus

Upon starting an activity, I want the screen to shift to x=5000, y=0. I used the following to try and achieve that:

//to aid in moving the focus to the main view.

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setFocusable(true);
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
params.setMargins(5000,0,10,10);
rl.addView(textView,params);
textView.requestFocus();
```

However it does not work, the focus is not moving to that location. Any help appreciated!

Comment: What you want to acheive? Change margins of TextView programatically?
First, put it in xml layout in RelativeLayout, then use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416087/how-to-set-margin-of-imageview-using-code-not-xml

Comment: No I want to move to x=5000,y=0 upon starting an activity, thanks

Answer (score 0):

From API 11 you can do the following

```
textView.setTranslationX(5000);
```

or if you want to change Y use:

```
textView.setTranslationY(your value expecting an int));
```

Comment: Hello this is not shifting the focus all the way to that position upon starting an activity, thanks for the reply.

Comment: What do you mean not shifting the focus all the way you mean it slide out side of the screen?

Comment: By sliding it off the screen to x=5000 I want the screen to move there too, thats why I thought requestfocus() would work on the textview once i moved it to that position

Comment: that would be possible if your rootview is a scrollview