# ListView with specific spacing between items

Tags: android, listview, spacing

I have a `ListView` and wish to have spacing between items increase/decrease depending on the two items. I basically have items alternate sides randomly and want the spacing to increase when the items are on opposite sides.
I know how to increase the spacing between all items equally but am at a loss when it comes to specific rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply compare the data of the corresponding list rows and add an appropriate margin or padding to the `View`.

Just an example (kinda hard to give specific help without seeing any of your code):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(someContext)
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent, false);

    if (position > 0) {
        Data previous = someDataset.get(position - 1);
        Data current = someDataset.get(position);

        if (previous.something() == current.something()) {
            // add margin or padding to row
        }
    }

    // set TextView texts, ImageView images etc., whatever your row has

    return row;
}
```

If you don't know how to add margin to a `View` programmatically, there are many existing questions for that, [here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3416242/3363481).

If you would rather add padding, just call the `setPadding()` method on your `View`.